# How to Freeze native scroll ionic with ionicScrollDelegate

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How can I freeze the scroll for an ion-scroll element that uses native scrolling on an element via `overflow-scroll="true"`?

calling `$ionicSCrollDelegate.freezeScroll(true)` does not work on native scroll in iOS.

Tagging Cordova because that's the core technology.

Comment: Is the spelling of `$ionicScrollDelegate` intentionally incorrect or a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a total hack (external from Ionic). It's not as pretty as controlling the delegate, but hey, it works.

```
<ion-scroll id="scroller"> ... </ion-scroll>

//freeze
scroller.css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
scroller.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');

//unfreeze
scroller.css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
scroller.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
```